# "что" as a relative pronoun

Tags: грамматика, местоимения

In these [verses](https://www.culture.ru/poems/35433/ta-chto-bez-videniya-spala) by Marina Tsvetaeva:

> Та, что без видения спала —
> Вздрогнула и встала.

I don't quite understand why we have "что" and not "кто". I thought that only "кто" could be used as a subject, while "что" was used as a complement.

Comment: "Что" can totally be used as a subject, e.g. "Что тебя беспокоит?" What's your question?

Comment: @SergeySlepov In your example, "что" is not a relative pronoun. My question is about "что" as a relative pronoun.

Comment: https://www.reddit.com/r/EnglishLearning/comments/b26x68/can_you_use_what_as_a_relative_pronoun/ happens in British English too.

Answer (score 7, accepted):

The use of «что» meaning «который» in reference to a person in modern Russian is either archaic or poetic. Modern fiction, as well as colloquial speech, tends to avoid such structures. But you can still find examples of it in old songs and poetry.

For instance:

Где эта улица, где этот дом?
Где эта девушка, что я влюблён? (В которую я влюблён)

In your sentence Та, что спала (та, которая спала).

Comment: Do you make a distinction between та, которая спала and та, кто спала?

Comment: Та, которая sounds better, та , кто sounds clumsy for natives, but perhaps it depends on the situation. For example тот, который живёт на крыше, и тот, кто живёт на крыше, are both idiomatic meaning the same

Comment: "- Где книга? - Какая? - Та, что я вчера принес." I dunno maybe it's a regional thing but this sounds completely normal to me and not archaic or poetic at all. Though the example you give is for sure archaic/poetic.

Comment: Мы здесь говорим о людях, а не о вещах, вы, похоже , не заметили. И вопрос об этом, я не вижу необходимости уточнять очевидное.

Comment: I should note that the usage of _что_ in these lyrics is not standard. You can replace _который_ with _что_ regardless of the case of _который_, but only if it isn't prepended with a preposition. _Та, которую я люблю_ and _та, что я люблю_ are both fine; _та, что я влюблён_ is not a good substitute for _та, в которую я влюблён_, because of the preposition _в_.

Answer (score 5):

Any of the combinations in *тот/та, кто/что …* can be used (as long as they reference people, of course), but *тот, кто …* and *та, что …* are [preferred](https://books.google.com/ngrams/graph?content=%D1%82%D0%B0%20%D0%BA%D1%82%D0%BE%2C%D1%82%D0%B0%20%D1%87%D1%82%D0%BE%2C%D1%82%D0%BE%D1%82%20%D0%BA%D1%82%D0%BE%2C%D1%82%D0%BE%D1%82%20%D1%87%D1%82%D0%BE&year_start=1810&year_end=2019&corpus=ru-2019&smoothing=8#):

[image]

*Тот, который* and *та, которая* can also be used, and they *might* be preferred when referencing a definite person (one who is already in the context of the conversation), same as in English "the one" vs. "one".

> - Кент, художник, не тот, который Рокуэлл Кент, а тот, который жил в восемнадцатом веке, пользовался лишь словесным самоописанием Сервантеса. //
>   *[Сергей Носов. Грачи улетели (2005)]*
> - Даже тот, кто не является футбольным фанатом (как, например, автор этих строк), прекрасно помнит его репортажи. *[Юлия Рахаева. Другой Брэдбери. Книжный развал // «Известия», 2001.11.11]*

In the examples above, replacing *кто* with *который* and vice versa would be a poor stylistic choice. But in many other cases they are interchangeable.